# How to filter Dynatrace metrics with request attributes using environment REST API

Tags: api, filter, request, attributes, dynatrace

Using the **Dynatrace SaaS GUI** in **Multidimensional analysis** menu I am able to split and filter metrics with request attributes, but I can't find any document on how is the syntax to do the same with the environment v2 API (/metrics/query).
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of the [metric query API](https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/dynatrace-api/environment-api/metric-v2/get-data-points/) describes the `metricSelector` parameter, which is used to select the metric to query and to perform operations on it, e.g. splitting by dimension or filtering based on some values.

You can develop and test the metric-selector in the UI via menu item "Metrics" -> then search for the metric and in the data-explorer build your metric query via "split by" and "filter", then the tab "Code" will show the corresponding metricSelector that you can use also in the query-API.

E.g. a possible metric-query looks like follows:

`sample.metric:filter(and(in("dt.entity.process_group_instance",entitySelector("type(process_group_instance),tag(~"Prod~")")))):splitBy("dt.entity.process_group_instance",rx_pid):avg:auto:sort(value(avg,descending)):limit(10)`

The documentation for the [metric selector](https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/dynatrace-api/environment-api/metric-v2/metric-selector/) explains details and contains many more examples.

Comment: Hi Centic, this documentation is ok for any metric but I can't find anything with "request attributes". How is the syntax to filter metrics using a request attribute?

Comment: You are right, it seems there is no dimension added for request attributes, only "service" is available on related metrics, so it might not be possible to filter metrics on request attribute currently.